# Spring boot @enableautoconfiguration(exclude= datasourceautoconfiguration.class ) not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jboss, jboss-eap-6

I have a standalone spring boot jar inside an EAR that has various other projects in it. This ear is deployed in jboss eap 6.3.

when I start the server I get an **error** as

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The following classes could not be excluded because they are not auto-configuration classes:  - org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration jboss eap

**Code:**

```java
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class PersistanceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PersistanceApplication.class, args);
    }
    public static void main1() {
         SpringApplication springApplication = 
                    new 
 SpringApplicationBuilder(PersistanceApplication.class)
                    .web(WebApplicationType.NONE)
                    .build();

            springApplication.run("");

    }

}
```

**pom.xml**:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>panacea</groupId>
    <artifactId>Persistance</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>IDCPersistance</name>
    <description>New saving</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency> 

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>           
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
                <configuration>
                  <archive>
                    <manifestFile>src/main/resources/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
                  </archive>
                </configuration>
              </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

But if I run that as a standalone application separately it works properly.
But when I run inside an EAR, I'm getting this error.

Comment: One thing you aren't using the Spring Boot plugin to properly create an executable jar. The fact that you are using this inside an EAR might be the cause of the trouble due to classloading (same classlaoded twice, in different classloaders then the instanceof check will fail).

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks, so how am I supposed to rectify this